# send exported certificate from keystore using curl

Tags: tomcat, ssl, curl, https, certificate

I followed this tutorial to set my tomcat ssl:
http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/

I named the keystore file to mystore2.jks instead of mkyongkeystore.
Then to the keystore I added another certificate like this.

```
keytool -genkey -alias testhim -keyalg RSA -keystore mystore2.jks
```

then exported it like this:

```
keytool -export -alias testhim -file forcurl.crt -keystore mystore2.jks
```

now I want to test my tomcat https using 'forcurl.crt'

```
curl https://localhost:8443 --cert forcurl.crt 

curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

how do I pass the passphrase? Should the exported certificate be crt file? 
Is the method correct, exporting a certificate from keystore that tomcat is pointing, and then using that certificate with curl to hit the tomcat url?

forcurl.crt looks like this, what is this encoding called. Not PEM for sure:

```
3082 036d 3082 0255 a003 0201 0202 0433
c4ed 0830 0d06 092a 8648 86f7 0d01 010b
0500 3067 310b 3009 0603 5504 0613 0264
6b31 1030 0e06 0355 0408 1307 7465 7374
6869 6d31 1030 0e06 0355 0407 1307 7465
7374 6869 6d31 1030 0e06 0355 040a 1307
7465 7374 6869 6d31 1030 0e06 0355 040b
1307 7465 7374 6869 6d31 1030 0e06 0355
0403 1307 7465 7374 6869 6d30 1e17 0d31
...
```

I was able to hit the url using the following command and get response:
curl https://localhost:8443 --insecure

I want no one to access the URL since it will be REST API. To access the url one needs to present his certificate.

I changed the tomcat>server.xml https connector to true clientAuth="true".

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/home/nowshad/dump/mystore2.jks"
         keystorePass="123456"/>
```

Then used:

```
curl  https://localhost:8443 --insecure -v
```

This is the output:

```
user@user-System:~$ curl  https://localhost:8443 --insecure -v
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:8443/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:8443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:8443
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a self-signed certificate, `curl https://localhost:8443 --insecure` should be sufficient to test.  If it is signed by a CA, then you just call it normally, `curl https://localhost:8443`.

The client doesn't need to have the certificate, especially not the key, in order to communicate.  The server will offer up the certificate when the client connects.

All the client needs is the CA certificate that signed the cert so it can verify whether or not it's valid.

Add `-v` to add verbose output to cURL.

Comment: Thanks curl https://localhost:8443 --insecure worked. I wanted to block access to everyone, only presenting certificate will make him legitimate user.